# Complement definition and question in algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

So suppose $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ and $V=V_1+V_2$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$. Then $V=V_1\oplus V_2$. Then we say $V_2$ is a complement of $V_1$ in $V$ and the other way around.

Now lets suppose $S=\{(1,2,1),(2,a,2)\}$ with $a\in \Bbb R$ and the subspace $V$ in $\Bbb R^3$ generated by S, $V=\langle S\rangle$.

Now is there a complement of $V$ for every $a \in \Bbb R $? And what about the basis of V?

If $V$ is generated by $S$, then each element in $V$ is a linear combinations of S. $$a=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+x_3a_3$$

I am not quite sure i understood the question. To satisfy the definition of complements i only need to define another set, say $S_1$ such that $S\cap S_1=\varnothing$. Now let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $S_1$. We have
$$\beta=y_1b_1+y_2b_2+y_3b_3$$

Now define a vector space G where $V,W\in G$ such that $G$ has the basis vector $g=\{a_1,a_2,a_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3)\}$.

This would fullfill the definiton of complement subspaces? Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement to $V$ exists for an arbitrary $a$, you only need to take an orthogonal complement to $V$ and since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is Hilbert space we obtain:
$$
\mathbb{R}^3 = V \oplus V^{\bot}
$$
About basis. If $a = 4$, then $2\times (1, 2, 1) = (2, 4, 2)$ so the basis of $V$ is one vector $e_1 = (1, 2, 1)$, in other cases the basis is $e_1 = (1, 2, 1)$ and $e_2 = (2, a, 2)$, because they are obviously linearly independent.

Comment: I actually havnt had hilbert space yet....I mainly wanted to ask if my understanding was correct....if you could take another look:) Thanks

Comment: Well, i don't fully understand notation $x = a_1x_1 +a_2x_2 + a_3 x_3$.Well, you not only need  $S \cap S_1 = \varnothing$, you also need $S + S_1 = \mathbb{R}^3$. Also, you have rather strange definition of vector space $G$.What you need, is just find the basis of $S$ and find linearly independent vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{R^3}$, such that $v_i$ doesn't in span$ S$ and span$(S, v_i) = \mathbb{R}^3$